# Как подключить к php счетчик на html?

Tags: javascript, html, php

Добрый день, хочу подключить счетчик на html5, он имеет свои JS. Если подключаю через include, то JS смешиваются с JS странички, и сайт теряет свой внешний вид, как можно ограничить действие встраиваемого JS на `<div JS on> </div JS off>` ?

Comment: Только если изменить код счетчика. Если путаются функции то меняй порядок подключенных скриптов

Comment: К сожалению не получится изменить порядок, т.к. двигатель WordPress, там всё по шаблонам.

Ну это не совсем счетчик, это график - http://habrahabr.ru/post/137744/ , есть еще какие-нибудь варианты?

Comment: если вордпресс то по кодексу в папке темы wp-content/themes/{название темы} в файле functions.php найдите строку wp_enqueue_script и попробуйте подключить корректно

Answer (score 1):

на странице плагина есть док, там написно что в плагин принимает элемент желательно по его ID 
вот код

```
(function () {
        var container = document.getElementById('container'),
```

у вас все именно так ?
++
может имеет смысл заменит код

```
function animate (t) {
```

на

```
var animate7 = function(t){
```